# How can i Transfer DNS zones to new server

Tags: migration

I want to migrate from my win server 2003 to a new server 2012
my server has running DNS service and i want to migrate all zones to new server .

Comment: Copy the zone files from one to the other?

Comment: The safe way: Make the new DNS server, add it to your DNS, transfer all roles to it, remove the old server.

Answer (score 1):

For AD integrated DNS it's really easy: you add the 2012 server as AD integrated DNS server, let DNS replicate the zonefiles, remove the old one and point your clients to the 2012 DNS server.

If it's non-AD-integrated it's still quite easy, you add the new one as secondary server, let DNS replicate the zonefiles, promote to primary and point the clients to the 2012 DNS server.

Or you manually export all zones and settings from server 2003 and import it in 2012.

The choice is yours, depending on you configuration.

There even exists [a detailed step-by-step](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/06/30/20-helpful-steps-migrating-windows-server-2003-to-2012-r2/), using yet some other options, by Microsoft.

Comment: How can i manually export all zones and settings from server 2003 and import it in 2012 ???

Comment: Either using `dnscmd` or "export" by hand, copying the zonefiles etc. from server 1 to server 2.

Comment: when i coppy al dns files from "C:\Windows\System32\dns" and copy them to New server, the zones no coppied 
do i right ?

Comment: _Export the DNS Configuration for all of the Standard Primary and Secondary Zones (Forward and Reverse) and export the DNS Registry keys (HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\Zones to the new Windows 2012 R2 Server (c:\export\DNS\zones.reg) then copy *.dns from %windir%\system32\dns to the new Windows 2012 R2 Server (c:\export\DNS)_